# How to use Webhook for Microsoft cognitive Speech to Text V3

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I'm trying to understand how to use a webhook in microsoft speech to text V3. According to the docs i was able to create a webhook and ping it. Now whenever a transcription is complete the webhook is called, but the body object in request is empty always and is pretty much of no use.
Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of the request, that you receive, should contain a content similar to this one

```json
{
  "self": "https://{CognitiveServicesEndpoint}/speechtotext/v3.0/transcriptions/{TranscriptionId}",
  "invocationId": "{InvocationId}"
}
```

You can do an HTTP GET on the `self` property of the body to get details on the entity. These are deliberately not included, due to possible trust concerns between the web hook receiver and the subscription owner.

Also, there should be a header in the request named `X-MicrosoftSpeechServices-Event`. It should contain the state of the transcription as one of the following, depending on what you subscribed for

- `TranscriptionCreation`
- `TranscriptionProcessing`
- `TranscriptionCompletion`
- `TranscriptionDeletion`

I just created a web hook with all the above transcription event types and I received the expected requests with the expected payload in the body. If you do not see the correct payload in the body, please let me know, which endpoint (region) you are using, so I can check that one specifically. There might be a bug in that specific datacenter.

Kind regards

Dirk

Comment: Hey Dirk, thank you for taking a look :), my location is "eastus" and i'm still not getting anything within the body but it does seem to have `X-MicrosoftSpeechServices-Event` header. If you need any more details about the request i'll share it with you .

Comment: I tried creating a transcription in that region. The web hook receiver reported the body to be 

{
  "self": "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/transcriptions/5c1d60b1-148f-4fc7-8eab-338d9e0fc340",
  "invocationId": "7fcc4c1e-19f3-47fe-a74a-df5db720bc63"
}

Please make sure, you de-serialize the body of the POST request in the web hook receiver correctly.

Comment: Oh!! Thanks mate, turns out it was a problem with serialization.

Comment: @D.Siemer any clue what names of X-MicrosoftSpeechServices-Event are allowed? Is there an "OnError" or "OnTranscriptionFailed" event or something? 
Docs are apparently missing that part completely.

Comment: The possible events you can subscribe to are:

datasetCreation

datasetProcessing

datasetCompletion

datasetDeletion

modelCreation

modelProcessing

modelCompletion

modelDeletion

evaluationCreation

evaluationProcessing

evaluationCompletion

evaluationDeletion

transcriptionCreation

transcriptionProcessing

transcriptionCompletion

transcriptionDeletion

endpointCreation

endpointProcessing

endpointCompletion

endpointDeletion

Comment: When looking for failures, you should subscribe to the .*Completion events, do a GET on the self link and look for the Status property of the response. There is only one event for entities reaching a terminal state. We don't offer different events for success and error.

Comment: The documentation is a bit frustrating to find, due to a visualization issue in the APIM. The documentation can be found here:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateHook
From there you can download the API definition. In the Swagger you can look for the WebHook definition of the POST body and in there you will find the "events" as property of type object with the allowed property names and types (boolean) for that object.

Comment: @D.Siemer thanks a lot, that was very helpful

Comment: An easier access to the Swagger file would be from here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/Speech/SpeechToText/stable/v3.0